# Making a url non clickable in task object

Tags: apex, visualforce, tasks, url

I have a requirement where I am storing some data in the description field(label Comments) in task object. The data consists on some url as well, which is remaining as clickable once it has been saved as a task. Is it possible to stop it? Is there any datatype which which make the link non-clickable?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a supported way to achieve this - Salesforce automatically converts any text that looks like a URL into a hyperlink.  In a Visualforce page you could use CSS to make the text look "normal" or Javascript to stop the link being clickable, but neither of those will work in a regular page.

There is an idea on this issue which you could vote on:

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l3oqAAA

As it doesn't have many votes currently, I suspect this behaviour won't be changing soon!